# Cree un Task con c# pero al guardarlo lanza un error DE ENSAMBLADO ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**ERROR:**

> "No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'TaskScheduler,
>   Version=1.3.2889.25680. Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=null' ni una
>   de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo
>   especificado."

**Mi código:**

```
        string Dia = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        short hra = Convert.ToInt16(textBox4.Text);
        short min = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);


        using (ScheduledTasks Tareas = new ScheduledTasks())

        {
            Task tarea = Tareas.CreateTask("Ejecutar secador de botas");

            tarea.ApplicationName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fishken SB\SecadorDeBotas           \SecadorBotas.exe";

            tarea.Comment = "Tarea que ejecuta programa secador de botas";            

            tarea.Creator = "USER";

            tarea.Priority = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;

            switch (Dia)
            {
                case "Lunes":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Monday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Martes":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Miercoles":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;

                case "Jueves":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Viernes":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Friday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Sabado":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Domingo":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: este error se produce cuando ejecutas desde el VS o cual lo haces desde el cliente ? agregas la libreria usando nuget?

Comment: Una vez que instalo la aplicación en el computador...

Comment: ejecutas desde el VS, agregas la libreria usando nuget debes publicar tu solucion te recomiendo que lo hagas en release y con la opcion AnyCPU. Tambien es importante que cheques la compatibilidad entre tu netframewok y las dll empaquetadas en nuget. exito.

Comment: Cual es la diferencia entre compilar y publicar?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que llevar junto al .exe la dll de la libreria para que el codigo pueda utilizarla
o en su defecto crear un instalador con la opcion de `publish` del VS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero debes asegurarte que junto a la app compilada debe estar las dll de teceros que utilices

Comment: Gracias Leandro, incluí la librería al proyecto de instalación y ya no aparece el error pero sigue sin lanzar la aplicación en la fecha que le indico...